# Multiple objects in array

Tags: modifiers, objects

Just wondering if there is a way to use multiple objects in an array.  For example first object would be a car, second would be a boat, etc.

**UPDATE**

hanks, I followed Robin' suggestion. Lukasz, thanks, but I need to modify the positions.

One more question on this. Is there anyway to assign the degree of rotation for each member of the group in the array? The five planes in the x axis are the grouped aircraft. The circle array and the plane array (vertical) are not pointed in the same direction. I'd like to be able to specify the z axis rotation of each individual of the group. I was able to get them to point in the same direction on the plane array, but that is not the objective.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Do you want to set each rotation by hand, or is there a pattern ?

Comment: Both would be nice.  Currently there is a pattern where the rotation for each object = # objects / 360.

Comment: Arrays of empties would go along way to help (but they are not implemented)

Answer (score 8):

Any single array can only contain instances of one object. But in a sense, you can, because you can nest arrays. You can have single element arrays; arrays of arrays; the start and end caps of an array can be arrays. That's sometimes useful, but start and end caps won't merge, if that's what you need, and offsets can sometimes be a bit tricky to set up.

One way to get a variety in evenly distributed objects is to use a particle system: here, distributing a Group of objects on the vertices of a 24-vertex mesh circle.

[image]

Make a Group of your objects, give the distributing mesh a particle system, and then set it up something like the illustration. (You don't need Physics, or anything like that). If you need to order your objects, you can 'Use Count' to set up repeating sequences.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add e.g. a cone and an icosphere.
2. Combine them with <kbd>**CTRL**</kbd>+<kbd>**J**</kbd>.
3. Apply Array.

Done.

Comment: (UV) Fair enough. Quick, and often exactly what you need.. but with the limitation that the relative positions of the cone and icosphere are then fixed.