# Is there a particle/array combination?

Tags: modifiers, particles

So basically what im asking, is if it is possible to create an array with multiple objects (like a particle system). Because I think it would be useful for say... a boardwalk, where you would want some of the planks to have hole in them or cracks, but dont want to manually place/edit the planks of wood.

Comment: You can have an array emit a particle collection .. see for example [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/161181/35559) or [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/122685/35559)

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to answer by assuming what you are trying to achieve because it isn't really clear.

- Add a collection and model your planks inside it.

[image]

- Outside the collection, add a plane object, then add an array modifier to it. In edit mode scale it along the y axis so that is is about the width of your planks.
- Add a particle system to this plane. Set it to "Hair", check "Advanced". Set the number to the number of planks you want to have.
- Right click the "Number" field and choose "Copy as new driver". Go back to the array modifier and right click in the "Count" field and choose "Paste Driver". Now you don't need to touch the array modifier again, it will be modified every time you want to add or retrieve planks in the particle settings.

[image]
 - Go back to the particle settings. Set the instancer to collection and choose the planks. Uncheck "Show emitter" (twice). Don't forget to check "Pick Random" to add variety. :

[image]

Modify it to look like this. You can tweak the "Randomize" fields to add a bit of variety in size and rotation. :
[image]

If you add a curve modifier between the array and the particle system, you can even go 3D !

[image]