# Array a collection of objects along a curve

Tags: modeling, animation, modifiers, objects

So I wanted to array this 3 bottles on a Spiral Curve

[image]

I Tried using the most normal way possible,  array and curve modifier , the bottles are stretched and the most importantly, only 1 bottle can be array-ed at a time...

Then I searched all over the internet and learned about DupliFaces, i parented the 3 bottle to a plane, and array that plane to the spiral curve, and this is the result

[image]

yes, it somehow worked **BUT** there is still some noticeable seperation between each 3 bottles
yes, it can somehow be tricked out by playing the offsets, but because its on a spiral curve, the bottom part overlaps at each other and looked weird

I found this Question that really relates to my question:

[Multiple objects in array](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/122681/multiple-objects-in-array)

but its very outdated, and no longer working on the newest version of blender

I'm still looking for a better way to array multiple objects in blender,

[image]

Because my friend can do it so easily and with great result in Cinema4D, I'm finding a way to do that in blender

Comment: This question might help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/165628/lamp-posts-correctly-oriented-instances-on-a-3d-curve

Comment: nice ! but still, its only array-ing 1 objects :/
i need to array more than 1 object

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To array several unique objects in order, you can use several instancer objects with different offsets along the curve.

### Instancers

For my example, I'll use three planes all with their origins at the center, but of course, you can use as many instancers as you have objects that need to be instanced.

[image: Planes]

The only important measurement here is the offset between the planes.

### Array

Add an *Array* modifier to the first instancer with a *Constant Offset* that is set to the distance between the planes times the number of objects you need to array (in my case, three times the distance).

[image: Array]

### Curve

I used the *Add Curve: Extra Objects* add-on to create an *Archimedean Spiral* using these settings:

[image: Archimedean Spiral]

To perfect the curve, I rotated the start and end handles around the Z; then, I used *Individual Origins* to scale all of the handles along the Z.

[image: Spiral Adjustment]

### Finishing Up

Add the *Curve* modifier to the first instancer and set the array *Count* parameter accordingly.

[image: Curve Modifier]

With all of the instancers selected, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>**L**</kbd> for the *Make Links* menu and click *Modifiers.**

[image: Copied]

If the tilt of the curve is not right, you can set it to *Z-Up.* I further adjusted the curve's tilt in edit mode using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>**T**</kbd>.

[image: Twist Method]

All that is left to do at this point is parent your objects to the instancers and set them to instance by faces.

[image: Face Instancing]

You can also angle the instances by rotating the instancer meshes in edit mode.

[image: Rotate Instancers]

## Ta-da!

[image: Tadaa!]

---

* *Modifiers cannot be linked, so it is actually copying not linking.*

Comment: Hehe.. I interpreted the spiral as flat, so I couldn't just use perspective to make the instances smaller towards the middle :D.

Comment: ahh so 3 objects using 1 curve,  not a collection of objects using one curve, interesting, I'll definitely try this method, and it seems this is the most promising method right now, I'll try to use the duplifaces thing too so the bottles doesnt get distorted,  btw love the color palette on the bottles ! hahahaha

Comment: I might end up posting another answer since I found a way to do it with one instancer and a particle system (based on Robin Betts' solution). And I just really like coffee color palettes :)

Comment: i'll be waiting for the update ! hahaha but right now I'm using your solution to finish up this project, thanks !

Comment: hello hiserod, just couple minutes a go i found a trick that will kinda "link" modifiers, its not really linking
so if you have already copied all the modifiers to the object, then if you want to modify it and affect all of them, you need to hold alt while using the number slider, it will change all of them, its for 2.93 alpha i believe

Comment: Yup, that Alt shortcut has been around for a while. You could also use drivers or some Python to "link" settings.

Answer (score 7):

At least [one of the answers](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/122685/35559) you referred to still works, but does need a couple of refinements to deal with this arrangement.

- Construct  a spiral with the desired (changing) frequency of vertices along its length. The shipped add on *Add Curve: Extra Objects* may provide what you need out of the box, but if you need more control over vertices, you could make an array of your own single-vertex meshes deformed down the curve, with an object-offset. If you scale the object, you can vary the distance between the vertices on the way down. or you could use proportional editing, before curve-deformation.
- Once your vertices are where you want them, you can convert the curve to a mesh
- Give the mesh a particle system, as previously described, emitting from vertices.
- The 'Render' is of a collection of your bottles, using 'Count', so they come out in order, repeatedly.
- This time, (strangely) you need to turn on Physics, so you can use the influence of a Texture
- Create a Spherical, or Quadratic Spherical Blend texture, centered on the spiral, set to influence 'Size', so the instances get smaller toward the middle.
- You can put the texture through a Color Ramp to reverse the scaling influence of the texture, and get finer control over the size-graduation.

[image]

The easiest thing would be to play with the file.. if you have any problems, I would be happy to edit this answer.

[image]

Comment: Ooo, I like this answer. It's particularly cool to learn --upon investigating the file-- that Blender points vertex normals outward from the origin by default. I never noticed that before!

Comment: @HISEROD   Came as a surprise to me, not long ago! Makes sense though, in the absence of faces.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I'll definitely try this, but i think it will be alittle hard because in my animation there will be changing of the offset, so the bottle will get further each other in the animation,  but i'll try this interesting method too, infact i tried the old version you post in the link i mentioned Thanks !

Comment: In the case of needing to change the offset during an animation, then maybe you would be better of deforming an array (of planes?) down the curve, and instancing the bottles on those. Then you could change the offset of the array. Or even shape-key a mesh of some kind, before deforming it down the curve.

Answer (score 2):

[sverchok](/questions/tagged/sverchok)

Here is an (admittedly somewhat incomplete) node based solution

[image: voila]

Comment: Could you include a node explanation and the add-on's name in your answer?

Comment: @HISEROD The add-ons name is there (in tiny writing) - it's Sverchok. As for an explanation, I fear we may be wandering slightly outside my pay grade.

Comment: I wonder, are Geometry Nodes ready for this?