# Flying cards effect

Tags: modeling

I want to recreate the flying cards effect (see example). It will be my own objects but I'd like to arrange them the same way (in a spiral pattern)

I'm newbie. I make some research but didn't find any tutorials on the subject.

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/211453/array-a-collection-of-objects-along-a-curve

Comment: Blender comes with an add-on named *Add Curves: Extra Objects*. You can enable it in the preferences (menu *Edit > Preferences*, then *Add-ons* tab). When enabled, you can add a spiral curve. Then add an *Array* and a *Curve* modifier to the card object. Make sure the card is aligned along the X-axis and the origin is at the edge. Keyframe the X location to animate the cards.