# How to create a bracelet chain with different objects arraying around a curve

Tags: modeling, modifiers, geometry-nodes

[image]

[image]

I want to wrap the three objects around this curve such that they appear like the beads in a sequence (cube, sphere and cone) and don't deform.

Comment: May I recommend to read this : https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/122685/177431 and that : https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/211484/177431 ?